# MVC dynamic model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> the model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[CapacityPlanner2.Models.Segment, CapacityPlanner2.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]

My view has `@model  Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>`

and I am passing the following `Dictionary<Project, Segment>`

Shouldn't that work?

My partial View:

```
@model Dictionary<dynamic, Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>>>
```

My Main view

```
@model  Dictionary<dynamic, Dictionary<dynamic, Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>>>>


@foreach (var kvp in Model) 
{   
    @Html.Partial("_part", kvp.Value)
}
```

I want added the partial view cause I want to reuse it. But before that everything works.

Comment: Please can you add the relevant HTML/jQuery and your model and controller code?

Comment: I've struggled with that **a lot**. I don't think that the current MVC version allows it.

Comment: This is a covariance issue. You can't pass `Dictionary<Project, Segment>` for a `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>`, as they are invariant. When you define your dictionary, you can use `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>` and still create it composed of `Project` keys and `Segment` values, and then pass that to your view. However, any time you feel the need to use dynamics, step back and *really* think about whether you should. If there's truly no other way, then perhaps you have to, but that's incredibly rare. Make every attempt to go strongly-typed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment you have to pass `dynamic` type when creating the model. Here's a working sample. But as also mentioned in the comment, please check if you really need `dynamic`, may be `interfaced model` would be enough.

```
    public ActionResult Testing()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>
        {
            {1, new Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>(new Project{Name = "P1"}, new Segment{Id = "S1"})},
        };

        return View(data);
    }

    @foreach (var d in @Model)
          {
                  var item1 = @d.Value.Item1 as Project;
                  var item2 = @d.Value.Item2 as Segment;
                  <p> @d.Key + ": "  + @item1.Name + " - " + @item2.Id</p>
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that you can only declare

```
@Model dynamic
```

and then cast it to anything